# How to localize URL's in .NET Core 2.x?

Tags: c#, url, asp.net-core, localization

I've already setup and have the localization working, configured both in `ConfigureServices()` and in `Configure()` like:

```
var locOptions = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>();
        app.UseRequestLocalization(locOptions.Value);
        app.UseRouter(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapMiddlewareRoute("{culture=en}/{*mvcRoute}", subApp =>
            {
                subApp.UseRequestLocalization(locOptions.Value);

                subApp.UseMvc(mvcRoutes =>
                {
                    mvcRoutes.MapRoute(
                        name: "default",
                        template: "{culture=en}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                });
            });
        }).Run(NotFoundHandler);
```

and working like `/fr/Home/Register` but when it comes to links like `<a asp-action="Register">Register</a>` they still produce the default request culture, the `en`.

So the generated links are like `/en/Home/Register` instead of `/fr/Home/Register`

Is there something that I'm missing to make it work with links too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `culture` route value for link and that's why the default culture is set. It's possible to add it using `asp-route-[data]` attribute

```
<a asp-action="Register" asp-route-culture="fr">Register</a>
```

In order to retrieve current request culture you can use `IRequestCultureFeature`. Get feature in the view

```
@{
    var cultureFeature = Context.Features.Get<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.IRequestCultureFeature>();
}
```

Use `IRequestCultureFeature.RequestCulture.Culture` to retrieve current culture

```
<a asp-action="Register" asp-route-culture="@(feature.RequestCulture.Culture)">Register</a>
```

Comment: I hoped for a cleaner/embedded solution, but if there's no other way, peace.